# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] vs Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")

Tags: php, asp.net, unicode, query-string, http-referer

Why $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] (PHP) and Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER") (ASP) return different result if query string has non english characters?

php return correct value but asp will not:

php: сабака

asp: ׁ׀°׀±׀°׀÷׀°

Comment: Interesting question! Is the ASP.NET one a direct quote? How are you outputting it?

Comment: In case you're using a web browser for the output, take a look at the encoding/charset in the page properties.

Comment: @Pekka, with response.write in asp and echo in php

Comment: @VolkerK, it same browser and i don't believe that it sends diff properties for each technology (php or asp)

Comment: @msony it it quite possible that the encoding header differs, check it, even if just to make sure.

Comment: "and i don't believe that it sends diff properties for each technology" - maybe not (though it's also possible), but the browser can very well **receive** different headers.

Comment: it’s definitely a charset conversion problem. UTF-8 to Latin-1 just looks like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html), characters not in ISO- 8859-1 should be specially encoded. Therefore it seems that whoever is sending you the headers is breaking the spec. See *field-content* and *TEXT*.

[4.2 Message Headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2)

> ```
> message-header = field-name ":" [ field-value ]
> field-name     = token
> field-value    = *( field-content | LWS )
> field-content  = <the OCTETs making up the field-value
>                  and consisting of either *TEXT or combinations
>                  of token, separators, and quoted-string>
> ```

[2.2 Basic Rules](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2.2)

> ```
> TEXT           = <any OCTET except CTLs,
>                  but including LWS>
> ```
>
> The TEXT rule is only used for descriptive field contents and values that are
>   not intended to be interpreted by the message parser. Words of *TEXT MAY contain characters from character sets other than ISO- 8859-1 [22] only when encoded according to the rules of RFC 2047 [[14](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt)].